# Parameterizable cross length

Tags: system-verilog

I've got a protocol that supports bursts, where each transaction is composed of `N` individual transfers. Each transfer has a unique index from `0` to `N-1`. I would like to cover that all transfer orders have been seen (i.e. `0 1 2 3`, `1 2 3 0`, `0 2 3 1`, etc.). The value of `N` is variable (though in my case I only care about 4 and 8 for now).

The naive approach would be to cover each index individually and cross them, but this would mean I would need multiple `covergroups`, one per each value of `N`.

For `N = 4`:

```
covergroup some_cg;
  coverpoint idxs[0];
  coverpoint idxs[1];
  coverpoint idxs[2];
  coverpoint idxs[3];

  cross idxs[0], idxs[1], idxs[2], idxs[3] {
    ignore_bins non_unique_idxs[] = some_func_that_computes_bins_for_4_idxs();
  }
endgroup
```

For `N = 8`:

```
covergroup some_cg;
  coverpoint idx[0];
  coverpoint idx[1];
  coverpoint idx[2];
  coverpoint idx[3];
  coverpoint idx[4];
  coverpoint idx[5];
  coverpoint idx[6];
  coverpoint idx[7];

  cross idx[0], idx[1], idx[2], idx[3], idx[4], idx[5], idx[6], idx[7] {
    ignore_bins non_unique_idxs[] = some_func_that_computes_bins_for_8_idxs();
  }
endgroup
```

The two functions that generate the ignore bins each have to return different types (queue of `struct` with 4/8 fields), even though conceptually the operation for computing all illegal combinations is similar, regardless of the value of `N`. This could probably be solved with some clever use of the streaming operator, to stream the contents of the `structs` into arrays of `N` elements. The issue of redundancy in the `covergroup` definitions remains though. The only way I can think of solving this is by generating the code.

Another idea would be to pack all indexes into a packed array of the appropriate size and cover that:

```
covergroup some_other_cg;
  coverpoint packed_idxs {
    ignore_bins non_unique_idxs[] = some_func_that_computes_bins_for_N_idxs();
  }
endgroup

// Probably won't compile, but it would also be possible to use the streaming op
// Idea is to pack into integral type
foreach (idxs[i])
  packed_idxs[i * idx_len +: len] = idxs[i];
```

It's a pain to debug coverage holes, as it's difficult to figure what transfer order a certain packed value belongs to, especially if the values are shown in decimal radix. I believe the way values are displayed varies from tool to tool and it's not possible to control this. I also don't see any possibility to give names to individual bins using strings.

I would welcome any input that would improve upon any of the two suggestions. The goal is to have one coverage wrapper class with a parameter for the number of transfers and to be able to instantiate that and get the coverage:

```
class transfer_orders_coverage #(int unsigned NUM_TRANSFERS);
  // ...
endclass
```

Comment: The use of streaming isn't all that tricky, actually. Assuming that the struct and the array definitions are "compatible", `{>>{a_array}} = a_struct` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Adding as and 'Answer' since it was too long for comment. Pardon me if I am not clear.

Can you add some logic **before sampling CG** and use some *input argument* that denotes array position of `idxs`? For the crosses, you can **maintain a packed array of size N** and make individual bits `1` when a particular pattern is detected. At the end of sim, you can sample the coverage for that pattern in some different CG.

Basically the idea is to offload logic inside the covergroups and add logic surrounding `sample` function. Here is a rough idea about what I was thinking.

```
class transfer_orders_coverage #(int unsigned N = 4);
  int idxs[N];
  bit [(N -1) : 0] pattern; // Make indexes HIGH according to sampled pattern
  // ...
  covergroup cross_cg;
    mycp_cross: coverpoint pattern{
      ignore_bins myignbn = {some_generic_function_for_N(pattern)};
    }
  endgroup

  covergroup indiv_cg with function sample (int index);
      mycp_indiv: coverpoint idxs[index]{
                    // some bins to be covered in ith position of idxs
                  }
  endgroup

  function new();
    cross_cg = new;
    indiv_cg = new;
  endfunction

  function bit [(N -1) : 0] some_generic_function_for_N(bit [(N -1) : 0] pattern);
    // check which bits in "pattern" are to be covered and which are to be ignored 
    //return some_modified_pattern;
  endfunction

  function void start();
    // Any logic for sampling ith position
    foreach(idxs[i]) begin
      indiv_cg.sample(i);
      pattern[i] = 1'b1;
    end
    cross_cg.sample();

  endfunction

endclass

module top();
  transfer_orders_coverage #(4) tr;
  initial begin
    tr = new;
    tr.start();
  end
endmodule
```

Let me know if it seems feasible or not.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'make individual bits 1 when a particular pattern is detected'. Within a burst, all indices are seen, it's the order that's different. Sampling can be done per burst, I don't see a reason to move anything to the end of the simulation.

Comment: One can sample it run time also. By pattern, I mean order of burst. Whenever different bursts (i believe it they're burst sizes) are detected, make some bit 1. Let's say when `0 1 2 3` is detected, make bit-0 as 1, when ` 1 2 3 0` is detected, make bit-1 as 1 and so on. This may require some more logic.

Comment: How is this more readable in the coverage analysis tool than just clumping them all together?

Comment: Agree it will be very difficult to visualize and debug. But this would reduce code dependency on `N` and redundant CG's. I believe cross will be difficult but individual coverage will be easy to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the following solution may work in this case.

```
covergroup some_cg (int num);
  4n_cp : coverpoint ({idxs[0], idxs[1], idxs[2], idxs[3]}) iff (num == 4)
  {
    option.weight = (num == 4) ? 1 : 0; // Weight might change depending on other coverpoints
    ignore_bins non_unique_index[] = <Your Function>;
  }

  8n_cp : coverpoint ({idxs[0], idxs[1], idxs[2], idxs[3], idxs[4], idxs[5], idxs[6], idxs[7]}) iff (num == 8)
  {
    option.weight = (num == 8) ? 1 : 0; // Weight might change depending on other coverpoints
    ignore_bins non_unique_index[] = <Your Function>;
  }
endgroup

// Where you instantiate covergroups 
some_cg c1 = new(4);
```

Let me know, how the above idea works.

Comment: Two covergroups would be better than this, since this leads to coverpoints that can never be sampled and will have to be excluded inside the coverage tool. At the same time, as with @sharvil111's answers, given a coverage DB with holes in it, how do you work out which combinations are missing?

Comment: I have added `option.weight` in the coverpoint to disable them for other instances. In coverage tool, I guess the auto generated bins will have the decimal equivalent of `{idxs[3], idxs[2], idxs[1], idxs[0]}` in their name. Wouldn't that help to identify which transaction order is not covered?